# Mouse drag releasing itself under Debian / Gnome 3

Tags: linux, debian, mouse, gnome

I currently experiencing problems when i try to drag with my mouse.

You can see it here, i try to select all the visible text by holding the left click:

https://ibb.co/mXqTJdZ

It is like i am releasing and re-clicking multiples times, but i'm not.

I'm under Debian Bullseye / Gnome 3.38.4, but the problem was here in Debian Buster / Gnome 3.30

With evtest i can see the events (again, i just click, hold, and release):

```
Event: time 1619623912.689252, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90001
Event: time 1619623912.689252, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 272 (BTN_LEFT), value 1
Event: time 1619623912.818225, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90001
Event: time 1619623912.818225, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 272 (BTN_LEFT), value 0
Event: time 1619623913.801254, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90001
Event: time 1619623913.801254, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 272 (BTN_LEFT), value 1
Event: time 1619623915.802232, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90001
Event: time 1619623915.802232, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 272 (BTN_LEFT), value 0
```

You can see there is release/press events (lines 3,4,5,6) but these are not related to my actions on the mouse.

There is no "ghost" events (the problem only appears when i'm holding the click, but the mouse does not click itself when i dont touch it)

Maybe my mouse is dead (its a good G502 mouse always connected to a workstation) ? A USB problem ? A Software problem ? How i can check this ?

It's is very annoying to copy/paste, to drag and drop, to drag selection. etc etc etc...

Thank you !

EDIT: As Thomas Guyot-Sionnest has said, it's probably an hardware issue, i found a video, it's not exactly the same problem, but the cause may be the same. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVlhNlZWTuw

Comment: Have you tried your mouse on another computer? I've seen many mouses act like this, it's most likely a hardware issue.

Comment: Have you tried connecting another mouse to this PC, or this Mouse to another PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution, and it is not because Linux or Gnome.

The problem is from corroded contacts in the mouse, so the solutions are :

- buy a new mouse
- dissassemble the mouse, and

  - change the microswitchs (you have to unsolder the old swithes to solder the new ones)
  - open the microswitches, and clean the contacts inside (very, very small parts..)

Here is the solution :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVlhNlZWTuw

Seems that Logitech G502 have frequently this kind of problems...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1140365)

Comment: Is this better ?